# Winappdriver findElement - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, winappdriver

am learning winappdriver and I try to run the below example.

```
  let driver = new WindowsDriver();
  await driver.createSession(defaultCaps);
  let element = await driver.findElement('//*[@ClassName="Edit"]');
```

but no matter how I use findElement, I always get the below error

nfo WD Proxy Determined the downstream protocol as 'MJSONWP'
dbug BaseDriver Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, name, class name, accessibility id

Should I initiate the driver differently. Can anybody point me on how to use findElement with winappdriver in javascript

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just include the strategy 'xpath':

```
  let driver = new WindowsDriver();
  await driver.createSession(defaultCaps);
  let element = await driver.findElement('xpath', '//*[@ClassName="Edit"]');
```

Comment: This one also works  `let element = await driver.elementByXPath(selectorval);`